# PrestaShop - Cannot login to back-office after upgrade (1.7.2.0 -> 1.7.7.4)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have upgraded PrestaShop on my local machine (Xampp, PHP 7.4, MariaDB 10.1.22) according to official PrestaShop devdocs: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/keeping-up-to-date/upgrade/

In front-office, everything seems to be okay. The problem I am facing is I cannot login into back-office now. After filling up correct email and pwd and click login button, it doesn't show any message and just reloads the page. If I fill up incorrect email or pwd, there is common error "The employee does not exist, or the password provided is incorrect."

I have also tried to login via incognito mode in Chrome, Opera or Firefox, but in each case the result is the same - reloading the login page.

PrestaShop domains in table ps_shop_url are ok. Variables PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN in ps_configuration seems to be ok too. I have also cleared the cache dirs (ps_root/var/cache, ps_root/cache, ps_root/app/cache) but again with no result.

Please, anyone could help?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:** After some debugging I found out what may causing this problem:
In AdminControllerCore@init method, there is some employee checking at line 2804 ( !$this->context->employee->isLoggedBack() ), and this function checks validity of logged employee in back-office. However the employee id is null and it seems the id is not loaded from cookie... but I dont know why...

**EDIT 2:** Finally, there is a problem with validating cookie-checksum in method Cookie@update at these lines:

```
        /* Check if cookie has not been modified */
        if (!isset($this->_content['checksum']) || $this->_content['checksum'] != $checksum) {
            $this->logout();
        }
```

The checksums are not the same. Hence it logs me out everytime... Anyone knows what is this behavior caused by? I can just comment the logout line out and it works, but I understand that is not proper solution and may be a security risk...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a probably a cache issue.

Install the [MyShopRepair](https://github.com/crezzur/myshoprepair) on your server.
Enable debug mode and click on the button "Clear cache".

After this you will have access to your shop again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have installed it and cleared cache and then I have tried it also in more browsers but unfortunately it does not help :-(

Comment: For transparency, it might be good to clarify that you are the author of MyShopRepair.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.7.7 is not compatible with PHP 7.4. Try downgrading it.

[image: PHP compatibility chart]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried to downgrade to PHP 7.3, but no effect. However PHP 7.4 does not show me any errors, so I do not suspect PHP versions as a main cause of this problem.